# NotImplementedException: OleDb is not implemented

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, oledb, oledbconnection

I m trying to read a dbf file using OleDB connection in Unity . I got a project in Visual Studio using C# which runs perfectly . Although when i try it in Unity i get NotImplementedException: OleDb is not implemented .

```
        static public void readDBF()
        {
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\\;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=;Password=;"); // give your path directly 
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from ydr.dbf", con); // update this query with your table name 
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                con.Close();
                int i = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                    PrintDataSet(ds);
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Empty");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var error = e.ToString();
                // check error details 
                throw;
            }



        }
```

Comment: Implementing a Interface requires (on the compiler level) that you to provide a definition for each and every function. However a function whose whole body is `throw new NotImplementException();` is entirely valid. It is used both as default value by the Intelli Sense (so the code stays compileable) and as the return for any Function that does not make sense for this case.

Comment: This function belongs to System.data dll . It is supposed to be fully implemented

Comment: That depends. This is Unity, so we are unclear about what the target framework is. And of course some other type might have gotten in the way of scoping.

Comment: Based on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/unity-scripting-upgrade?view=vs-2019 it is supposed to target net 4.x where if i am not wrong OleDB and Odbc connections are fully implemented .Also in VS refferences in my unity script i can see that System.Data.OleDb exists .

Comment: Nowadays it is suppossed to target .NET Core or Framework 4.0 and later. In practice for a really long time it targetted Mono instead, because that was literally the only option. We could have a project with such a old target. And of course OleDB was never supported in Mono: https://www.mono-project.com/archived/ole_db/

Comment: I am getting a bit confused about what should i do . Since nowadays in every update since unity 2018 it is stable supported why they are not implemented ? There is no probable solution for using OleDB ? If not what could i do for reading my dbf files ?

Comment: The question is: What is your target Framework in the Project Properties? Mono? .NET Core? .NET Framework? Wich version?

Comment: In project settings i use : 
Scripting runtime version : .NET 4.x Equivalent .
Sripting Backend : Mono (i tried il2cpp option but doesnt change anything) .
Api Compatibility Level : .Net 4.x

Comment: At this time it might be easiest to get rid of the OleDB use. I mean it is a very dated thing. Even at it's best, it never supported named SQL Paramters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8 If the Database is fixed, maybe you could make a seperate process that accesses the DB and have this and the main application talk via any IPC approach? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/interprocess-communications